# Strtotime function bug on Sunday

Tags: php, strtotime

Every Sunday, the strtotime function is doing weird stuff on my schedule website. It shows next week's date instead of +2 weeks.

My code:

```
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
    $time = time();
    //Check the date of Monday and Sunday from 2 weeks later.
    $monday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( '+1 week monday' ) );
    $sunday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( '+2 week sunday' ) );
    //Check the weeknumber of this week and add 2, so that it shows the weeknumber of 2 weeks later.
    $weekdata = date("W", strtotime('+1 day', $time));
    $weeknumber = $weekdata + 2;
```

`$Weeknumber` shows correct information: 42, but `$monday` and `$sunday` shows next week's monday and sunday (03-10-2016 | 09-10-2016), but I want to have it show (10-10-2016 | 16-10-2016)

Also, is there a way to make the weeks start at monday instead of sunday? Because, on the "this week" page, it already shows data from week 26-09-2016 | 02-10-2016 instead of 19-09-2016 | 25-10-2016.

Comment: I'm not sure what should be wrong. It is working as expected. The next week's sunday **is** the 2nd october. And requesting the monday makes it the 3rd october.

Comment: I have to concur with @CharlotteDunois it seems to be working as one would expect

Comment: As toy setting the day that is deemed to be the start of a week see `http://php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.setfirstdayofweek.php`

Comment: Where I live, the week starts on monday and ends on sunday. So today, it should show 19-09-2016 | 25-10-2016 on the "this week" page, because the week didn't end yet.

Comment: It does. https://3v4l.org/7CiIT

Comment: Relevant (fixed) bug. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740 Check your PHP version and upgrade if affected

Comment: Not for me, I'm running PHP version 5.5.31. I can't upgrade it. I bought a webhosting packet, so I can't change things from the server.

Comment: Ask your hosting provider to upgrade PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strtotime function bug happens on PHP version 5.5.31. Upgrade your PHP version or try the fix below.

So I've fixed the bug with an if/else statement.

```
    $time = time();
    //Check the date of monday and sunday from this week.
    //Strtotime() bug on PHP version 5.5.31. Bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740
    if(date("l") == "Sunday"){
        $monday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( 'monday last week' ) );
        $sunday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( 'sunday last week' ) );
        //Check the weeknumber of this week.
        $weeknumber = date("W", strtotime('+0 day', $time));
    } else {
        $monday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( 'monday this week' ) );
        $sunday = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( 'sunday this week' ) );
        //Check the weeknumber of this week.
        $weeknumber = date("W", strtotime('+1 day', $time));
    }
```

Since the bug only happened on sunday, I made the if/else statement only check for sunday and not for the other days. If today is not sunday, it runs the else code, which is the normal way of getting this week's data. I'll see if the code works 100% when today is not sunday, but another day of the week.

I just wanted to show my solution to this problem to the people who's going to visit this question in the future.